# Footer won't stay at bottom in chrome on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I am trying to figure out why my footer won't stay at the bottom of the page on a mobile browser in chrome and safari. When you select an image, it moves up towards the top, depending upon image size. Here is a link to my site: http://aswanson.net/KiloArt/visions.html

Comment: Is your website responsive?

Comment: yes it is for mobile devices

Comment: It's your JavaScript. It has this: `$('.secondaryImg').click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#Img').offset().top},
        '2000');
});`

Comment: this has nothing to do with it. I have since used a fixed position footer, I am over it, thanks anyway